# 「砂を噛むように味__ない。」: Which particle(s) to use best, and how do the meanings differ?

Tags: grammar, particles

The sentence I encountered was originally:

> 「砂を噛むように味のない。」

Which I would translate as follows:

> (Something) lacks taste so much that it is just like chewing on sand.
>   *Don't try this at home.

I began to wonder if I changed the particle の with a different particle, when would the meaning actually change, and when would it become ungrammatical.

Below are the variations I can think of, and that which appear grammatical to me,  along with the meanings I think they have. The translation may well be unnatural.

> 砂を噛むように味がない。
>   (There is / This is) no taste like chewing on sand.
>
> 砂を噛むように味がある。
>   The taste that is like chewing on sand exists. This has the taste like chewing on sand.
>
> 砂を噛むように味である。
>   This taste is like chewing on sand.
>
> 砂を噛むように味　では/じゃ　ない。 
>    This taste is not like chewing on sand.

Again, I try to retain a more literal translation irrespective of naturalness, because I think this helps comparing the difference.

I believe this may be an issue many beginners such as yours truly encounter. I would really appreciate it if anyone could take a stab at this for me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think 砂を噛むように味のない is bit unnatural, because a noun is necessary after 味のない like 砂を噛むように味のない昼飯.

砂を噛むように味がない is natural.

砂を噛むように味がある would be grammatically correct, but it is not appropriate for a metaphor of taste.

砂を噛むように味である(はない) is unnatural. It is 砂を噛むような味である(はない). You must change continuous form ように to attributive form ような.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. However, I still have trouble deciding the meaning of each variation. {砂を噛むように}味がない: tasteless; {砂を噛むような味}である: tasteless; {砂を噛むような味}はない: not tasteless. Is this understanding correct? もしお暇があれば、ご教授おねがいいたします。

Comment: 砂を噛むように味がない is "It is tasteless like chewing sand. 砂を噛むような味である is "It has (is) the taste like chewing sand". 砂を噛むような味はない is "It doesn't has (isn't) the taste like chewing sand".